# How to retrive data from sqlite using content provider with more than one parameter

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working on Android app that let the user add some data and then do queries on the data, Example : User can add some doctors information like (Name, phone, city etc...) then the user can query the doctors database to retrieve the doctors in a specific parameters for example city.

I have this code :

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    qb.setTables(DOC_TABLE_NAME);

    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case DOC:
            qb.setProjectionMap(DOC_PROJECTION_MAP);
            break;
        case DOC_ID:
            qb.appendWhere( _ID + "=" + uri.getPathSegments().get(1));
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }
    if (sortOrder == null || sortOrder == ""){

        sortOrder = _ID;
    }
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
            null, null, sortOrder);

    c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

    return c;
}
```

What should I add to the cases the retriever a doctors on more than one parameter example : id, name, city. should i add this :

```
case DOC_ID_NAME_CITY:
    qb.appendWhere( _ID + "=" + uri.getPathSegments().get(1));
    qb.appendWhere( Name + "=" + uri.getPathSegments().get(2));
    qb.appendWhere( City + "=" + uri.getPathSegments().get(3));
break;
```

Also how to call it ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on this piece of code that will provide a vast idea how to retrieve  more than values

```
public String allusers()
{
    Log.d("ALLusers in db", "working");
    String result="";

    String []columns=new String[]{KEY_EMAIL_new,KEY_PASWORD_new};
    Cursor c= ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE_New, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    int iemail=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL_new);
    int ipassword=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PASWORD_new);
    for (c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
    {
        result=result+c.getString(iemail)+"         "+c.getString(ipassword)+"      "+ "\n";

    }

    return result;
}
```

I am getting all emails and passwords.You can modify this code according to requirement like if you need just one doctor data then do not make it a loop.I am looping here as i need all users.